# Android why are Notifications firing late after replacing JobIntentService with WorkManager?

Tags: broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-workmanager

JobIntentService class is deprecated so I tried to replace the class with WorkManager so I can reset calendar date alarms after a device reboot.  When the alarms are triggered a Notification is fired.  Unfortunately, Notifications are no longer firing at exact alarm time but with a long delay (1 to 3 minutes after the reboot on a Samsung Galaxy S7 phone running Android 8.0.0).

The RebootReceiver class receives the BOOT_COMPLETED action after the device is rebooted.  The RebootReceiver enqueues a OneTimeWorkRequest that should run immediately in the RebootWorker class.  The Worker is used to reset all of the pendingIntents for Alarm dates that are saved in a Room database.  I originally set up the JobIntentService because there could be hundreds of pending alarms that need to be reset after a device reboot so I wanted the alarm resets to occur in the background.  I thought I could use WorkManager to immediately execute after the BOOT_COMPLETED action so that the alarm pendingIntents would be immediately reset.  Then I expected the alarms to trigger the Notifications to fire at the exact alarm time.

In my test case using WorkManager, I only set up two calendar due dates so there are only two alarms.  I also tried adding ".setExpedited()..." to the OneTimeWorkRequest and that did not change anything.  It should not take 1-3 minutes for the Notifications to fire after the alarms are triggered.

Update:  I added test for SDK_Int >= 26 to receive ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED and had same delayed firings for the Notifications.

What am I missing here?  Why are Notifications firing so late after the alarms are triggered?

AndroidManifest

```
<manifest ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <application...
        <receiver
            android:name=".RebootReceiver"
            <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"  />                
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
       </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

RebootReceiver

```
public class RebootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent != null) {

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action != null) {

            if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED) || action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) ||
                    action.equals(QUICKBOOT_POWERON) || action.equals(HTC_QUICKBOOT)) {

                    resetAlarmsWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(RebootWorker.class)
                        // this also did not work: ".setExpedited(OutOfQuotaPolicy.RUN_AS_NON_EXPEDITED_WORK_REQUEST)"
                        .build();
                    WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(resetAlarmsWorkRequest);
                }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

RebootWorker

```
public class RebootWorker extends Worker {

    private CardRepository reposit;
    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private Intent brIntent3;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent3;
    private Context mContext;

    public RebootWorker(
        @NonNull Context context,
        @NonNull WorkerParameters parameters) {
        super(context, parameters);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @SuppressLint("UnspecifiedImmutableFlag")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        try {
       
            reposit = new CardRepository(mContext);            
            alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Calendar cal3 = Calendar.getInstance();

            List<Card> resetNotificationsList = reposit.getNotifications();
            // Cycle through the Room database rows to get the Notifications data.      
            for (Card card: resetNotificationsList) {
            
                if (card == null) {
                    break;
                }
            
                cal3.setTimeInMillis(quickcard.getDuedatentime());                
                if (cal3.getTimeInMillis() > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                    brIntent3 = new Intent(mContext, AlarmReceiver.class);
                    brIntent3.setAction("DueAlarm");
                    brIntent3.setData(Uri.parse("http://" + quickcard.getId()));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                        pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0, brIntent3,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  
                    } else {
                        pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0, brIntent3,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  
                    }
                
                    int SDK_INT3 = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                    if (SDK_INT3 >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (alarmManager != null) { 
                            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
                            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            cal3.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent3);
                            // I also tried "alarmManager.setAlarmClock()..." here, and that did not work either.
                        }
                    } else if (SDK_INT3 >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {                        
                        if (alarmManager != null) {
                            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal3.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent3);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (alarmManager != null) {
                            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal3.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent3);
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }           
            return Result.success();
        } catch (Throwable throwable) { 
            Log.e(TAG,"Error tring to reset alarms after devive reboot", throwable);
            return Result.failure();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want exact alarm, AlarmManager is your choice.

I don't think WorkManager should be used in your case, since it offers no exact guarantee WHEN it will be executed, it just gives you a promise that it will sometime in the future. All this to improve battery life.

From documentation:
Immediate: Tasks that must begin immediately and complete soon. **May** be expedited.

Expedited work:
You can use WorkManager to schedule immediate work for execution in the background. You should use Expedited work for tasks that are important to the user and which complete **within a few minutes**.

So 1 to 3 minutes is what Expedited work offers to you.

Comment: Perhaps you are not understanding my use case.  The code above shows I use AlarmManager.  And say the user has set 100 future alarms that have not fired yet.  Now the user reboots their phone.  So the app has to reset all 100 of the future pendingIntents so the AlarmManager will fire the Notifications.  Since there are so many pendingIntents to reset right after the reboot I put the AlarmManager code inside of a WorkManager so the resetting would occur on a background thread.  My hope was that would not affect the firing of any of the 100 future alarms that then fire Notifications.